# deploy symfony 3 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, lamp, symfony

I try to run a project with symfony 3 on ubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04LTS, Apache 2.4.7 , MYSQL 5.5.49, php 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16). But I have this error when I run the web/app_dev.phpUnable to find template

```
Unable to find template "PolarBundle:Default:index.html.twig" (looked into: /var/www/html/polarUTC/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form, /var/www/html/polarUTC/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views).
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
1 linked Exception: Twig_Error_Loader »
```

I try to run in WAMP and MAMP and I don't have problem. 
I check the web/config.php and I have no error.

Thank you for your help

Bye,

Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu file structure is case sensitive, so be careful on that. Many developers making this mistake when they are working on MAC or Windows.

I'd suggest you to use Homestead instead of MAMP or WAMP like tools.